# Sorting by Rating when using Solr on product listing

Tags: magento-enterprise, product-list, catalogsearch, search, solr

We are using Solr on Magento Enterprise. We original had sort by rating working on the product listing page, when using normal Magento search, with a Modification we made, but it doesn't work when searching with Solr.

We can't find any good information out there on how to pass data like ratings over to Solr, so I figured to post and see if anyone has any experience passing custom data from a non product table over to Solr and associating that to product data.